# Single addscalar in the query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, spring-mvc

Here is my sql query

```
session.createSQLQuery("select *, concat(country_code,contact_number) as phone_no from student").addScalar("phone_no", StringType.INSTANCE);
```

Now I am getting only phone_no in result, how can I get all other information without adding so many addScalar in that?

Answer (score 0):

```
session.createSQLQuery("select * from student").addEntity(student.class).list;
```

Or

```
session.createSQLQuery("select * from student").addEntity(student.class).list();
```

Comment: I agree but the column I am getting from the table isn't in that bean. Let me edit the question again.